# Get entire Mongo collection with/without locking?

Tags: mongodb

On startup an instance of my service needs to load entire Mongo collection. Don't ask why. I expect it to be `100 mb > x < 500 mb` in size and contain no more than `1M` lightweight documents.

What is the best way to implement it, trading consistency for availability and latency?

My plan is to have both [find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) and [watch()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.watch/#db.collection.watch) concurrently. The first one would give me an iterator over all docs in the collection and the second one will notify me upon changes that might have happened with data meanwhile.

But is there better way?

P.S. Can read/write concerns help me here?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using  a transaction and [snapshot read concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern-snapshot/).

Comment: Why? What's the benefit, what can go wrong otherwise?

Comment: Are you asking because you don't understand snapshot read concern or because you haven't read up on it at all?

Comment: I am asking for arguments.

Comment: Your find+watch approach is intrinsically racy which I think is obvious. Snapshot read concern is not.

Comment: But wouldn’t transaction + snapshot do the opposite thing and trade availability, latency for consistency?

Comment: In my particular use case it is much better to get stale data and update it later, when watch() triggers, then wait for actual data.

Comment: I don't know why you think that but you can benchmark if this is a serious concern.

Comment: Especially availability, I really don't see how anything we are discussing affects availability.

Comment: Think of snapshotting. Unless you go with local, at least quorum sync is required to agree upon data sent by DB. More than that, long-running transactions harm availability in terms of slowing down concurrent reads/writes that might be done by other instances of the same service or other services.

Comment: If by "quorum sync" you mean that you think database nodes have to talk to each other per operation to use a majority-committed snapshot, this isn't how MongoDB (and probably the vast majority of databases) work. Majority read doesn't imply latest data, you need to read from primary to get that. Locks on transactions - sure, benchmark if you are concerned.

Comment: Yeah, in order to read quorum snapshot nodes need to agree upon committed transactions across each quorum member. No matter what’s the implementation, it obviously requires extra efforts.

Comment: That is done regardless of whether you use read concern snapshot or not.

Comment: «Extra efforts» in terms of availability first of all: for N nodes to agree upon something those N nodes must be up and running. That's what I mean to say.